# Send 301 redirect in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

With this [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/) handler:

```haskell
myR :: Handler Html
myR = redirect HomeR
```

I can redirect using the 303/302 status code according to [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:redirect)

The documentation states that [redirectWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:redirectWith) shall be used for other status codes. What would be an example of using `redirectWith` with a 301 status code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an example in the `test/YesodCoreTest/Redirect.hs` file available in the current [Yesod 1.4.9.1 archive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/yesod-core-1.4.9.1.tar.gz):

```haskell
import qualified Network.HTTP.Types as H

myR :: Handler Html
myR = redirectWith H.status301 HomeR
```

For a list of available response codes, see the [Network.HTTP.Types documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types/docs/Network-HTTP-Types.html).